# Is there any method to run perf under WSL?

Tags: linux, windows-subsystem-for-linux, perf

When I wanted to run perf under WSL, I met the follow question:

> WARNING: perf not found for kernel 4.4.0-18362
>
> You may need to install the following packages for this specific kernel:
>
> linux-tools-4.4.0-18362-Microsoft
>
> linux-cloud-tools-4.4.0-18362-Microsoft
>
> You may also want to install one of the following packages to keep up to date:
>
> linux-tools-Microsoft
>
> linux-cloud-tools-Microsoft

But I can't find packages called `linux-tools-4.4.0-18362-Microsoft` or `linux-cloud-tools-4.4.0-18362-Microsoft`. I guess the package names are generated automatically.

I also tried to use perf in docker container. However, docker container use the same kernel as the hosts.

Is there any method to run perf under WSL?

---

I heard that perf can be used in WSL2. But after I upgraded to WSL2, it shows the similar error message:

> WARNING: perf not found for kernel 4.19.84-microsoft
>
> You may need to install the following packages for this specific
>   kernel:
>
> ```
> linux-tools-4.19.84-microsoft-standard
>
> linux-cloud-tools-4.19.84-microsoft-standard
> ```
>
> You may also want to install one of the following packages to keep
>   up to date:
>
> ```
> linux-tools-standard
>
> linux-cloud-tools-standard
> ```

Comment: In WSL2, perf can be used

Comment: @Biswapriyo Hi, I upgraded wsl1 to wsl2. However, it shows the semilar error message in wsl1:

Comment: Did you install any `linux*-tools*` package(s) that you can see in `aptitute` or whatever package-manager you use?  Your 2nd error message even lists some package names to install.

Comment: @PeterCordes Hi, I searched for these packages but found nothing. I guess these names are generated automatically. I found the correct answer below.

Comment: It didn't say that in your question so it seemed like there'd be some hope that the distro would package `linux-tools` since the kernel supports `perf`.  But apparently not.  Silly Microsoft :/

Answer (score 82, accepted):

> WARNING: perf not found for kernel 4.19.84-microsoft

Because WSL2 uses custom Linux kernel. Its source code can be found here
[microsoft/WSL2-Linux-Kernel](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL2-Linux-Kernel.git). We have to compile perf tools from it.

### Procedure

- Install required build packages. If you are using Ubuntu in WSL2 this is the
  required command:

```
sudo apt install build-essential flex bison libssl-dev libelf-dev
```

- Clone the WSL2 Linux kernel repository:

```
git clone --depth=1 https://github.com/microsoft/WSL2-Linux-Kernel.git
```

- Go to perf folder and compile it:

```
cd WSL2-Linux-Kernel/tools/perf
make
```

`perf` executable file will be in that folder.

Comment: Perf tool sources have standalone version at https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/tools/perf/ which is easier to use than doing full linux kernel git checkout or download. This site have perf for several recent versions of upstream linux kernel; they should work for any kernel. Or you can try to generate same targz file from WSL2 git with `make perf-targz-src-pkg`. Also: did you check the generated perf executable - what works and what does not; what is in `perf list`, what says perf stat for simple "echo 1", are there hardware events?

Comment: @osgx I didn't check every options but `./perf stat` works as usual.

Comment: Make sure you have WSL 2 installed other wise you will get `perf_event_open(..., 0) failed unexpectedly with error 22 (Invalid argument)
` as described here: https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/329#issuecomment-564454956

Comment: I'm getting this:-

Error:  Unable to find debugfs/tracefs
Hint:   Was your kernel compiled with debugfs/tracefs support?
Hint:   Is the debugfs/tracefs filesystem mounted?
Hint:   Try 'sudo mount -t debugfs nodev /sys/kernel/debug'
rebroad@J3PMPJP:~/bin$ sudo mount -t debugfs nodev /sys/kernel/debug
mount: /sys/kernel/debug: unknown filesystem type 'debugfs'.

Comment: hello @Biswapriyo , can you help me about an issue. I have done all of these, but i get this msg in the perf folder: WARNING: perf not found for kernel 5.10.16.3-microsoft

Comment: I succeed too run `perf`, but only generic event are available for me. No hardware events (like the number of AVX arithmetic operation or the amount of read/written MiB from/to RAM on Skylake). I used the version 5.10. Interestingly, `perf top` does not see Windows application.

Comment: @JérômeRichard: When you say "generic events" worked, do you mean hardware PMU events like `cycles` and `instructions`, but not uarch-specific stuff like `mem_inst_retired.any`?  Or do you only mean kernel software events like `task-clock`, `page-faults`, and `context-switches`, but not `instructions`?  A recent answer installed a non-WLS2 version of `perf` and found no HW events were working.

Comment: @PeterCordes I should have said system events rather than generic events. `perf stat` reports: task-clock, context-switches, cpu-migrations, page-faults. But the others like instructions or cycles are unsupported.

Comment: @JérômeRichard: Ok, that makes more sense, I'd expect either no PMU events or all of them.  With none being most likely since it runs in a VM, thus the hypervisor would need to virtualize the PMU for it to work.

Answer (score 42):

You can install [`linux-tools-generic`](https://pkgs.org/download/linux-tools-generic).

```
apt install linux-tools-generic
```

Then run `perf` using the install path `/usr/lib/linux-tools/<linux-version>-generic/perf`.

Some tools, like [`flamegraph`](https://lib.rs/crates/flamegraph), will use environment variable `PERF` as the `perf` path.

```
PERF=/usr/lib/linux-tools/<linux-version>-generic/perf flamegraph -- my_program
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer.  When I was typing perf in the cli it was using `/usr/bin/perf` instead of `/usr/lib/linux-tools/5.4.0-104-generic/perf`

Answer (score 11):

The accepted answer works. However, some features are missing.

In order to get useful and demangled information, I had to install the following libs and then run `make` again.

- `libbabeltrace-dev`
- `libunwind-dev`
- `libdw-dev`
- `binutils-dev`
- `libiberty-dev`

I'm not sure if all of them are necessary. However, those are adequate for `cargo-flamegraph` (my usecase) to work.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31250818)

Comment: This is actually a really good hint.

Comment: This is helpful. thanks. I also had to install `libssl-dev` to enable the `libcrypto` requirement.

Comment: Here's a bigger list: https://gist.github.com/LoganDark/8f9ba939bbe4b73d057ceee46b07e20f

Answer (score 9):

You could install some generic version of perf, rather than the WSL2 version, like:

```
sudo apt install linux-tools-5.4.0-126-generic linux-tools-common
```

And then when you run perf, it will error out, like:

```
$ perf
WARNING: perf not found for kernel 5.10.16.3-microsoft

  You may need to install the following packages for this specific kernel:
    linux-tools-5.10.16.3-microsoft-standard-WSL2
    linux-cloud-tools-5.10.16.3-microsoft-standard-WSL2
```

This is because script `/usr/bin/perf` always trying to get the perf binary from `uname -r`

```
$ grep uname `which perf`
full_version=`uname -r`
```

We could replace /usr/bin/perf with the actual perf :

```
mv /usr/bin/perf /usr/bin/perf.bk && ln -s /usr/lib/linux-tools/5.4.0-126-generic/perf /usr/bin/perf
```

and then:

```
$ perf stat ls 1>/dev/null

 Performance counter stats for 'ls':

              1.79 msec task-clock:u              #    0.827 CPUs utilized
                 0      context-switches:u        #    0.000 K/sec
                 0      cpu-migrations:u          #    0.000 K/sec
               112      page-faults:u             #    0.063 M/sec
   <not supported>      cycles:u
   <not supported>      instructions:u
   <not supported>      branches:u
   <not supported>      branch-misses:u

       0.002158900 seconds time elapsed

       0.002182000 seconds user
       0.000000000 seconds sys
```

I think it is expected the hardware/cache counters are not available on WSL2

Comment: WSL2 runs inside a VM.  For HW PMU events to work, the VM + hypervisor would need to support it, so it doesn't let you profile stuff outside of guest VM.  (And potentially even get last-branch-record tracing).  Last I read, there was some work happening to make KVM support PMU access for Linux-on-Linux virtualization, but IDK if that ever got completed.  And clearly WSL2 doesn't do it.

Comment: This is exactly the kind of thing I get now on my machine too. Thank you for clarifying this long standing issue. This is sad most events do not work since it makes `perf` nearly useless in WSL...

Comment: This is the only way I could get Hotspot to work on WSL2.

Answer (score 3):

If you follow the accepted answer, make sure you read the complains the make command prints at the start, as it might be missing some headers and disables functionality.

For me it disabled tui, gtk and demangling to name a few features.

Comment: So which specific packages did you have to install to satisfy those optional dependencies and enable those features?  That would make this answer more useful to future readers.

Answer (score 1):

I have experienced an error when trying to run `perf stat` using both the compiled and `linux-tools-generic` versions:

```
./perf stat -d ls
Error:
The sys_perf_event_open() syscall returned with 22 (Invalid argument) for event (slots:u).
/bin/dmesg | grep -i perf may provide additional information.
```

Any rituals for updating/enabling/disable WSL2 or reinstalling Ubuntu image didn't fix it.
I have found an explanation in some [newsletter](https://lore.kernel.org/lkml/0088a5f2-ec17-a967-27e5-342e97eafe11@oracle.com/T/):

> Add kvm@vger.kernel.org as this issue is in virtualization env.
>
> The topdown metrics events became default since commit 42641d6f4d15
> ("perf stat: Add Topdown metrics events as default events"). The perf
> will use 'slots' if the /sys/bus/event_source/devices/cpu/events/slots
> is available.
>
> Unfortunately, the 'slots' may not be supported in the virualization
> environment. The hypervisor may not expose the 'slots' counter to the
> VM in cpuid. As a result, the kernel may disable topdown slots and
> metrics events in intel_pmu_init() if slots event is not in CPUID.
> E.g., both c->weight and c->idxmsk64 are set to 0.
>
> There will be below error on Icelake VM since 'slots' is the leader:
>
> $ perf stat Error: The sys_perf_event_open() syscall returned with 22
> (Invalid argument) for event (slots). /bin/dmesg | grep -i perf may
> provide additional information.
>
> This is because the stat_handle_error() returns COUNTER_FATAL when the
> 'slots' is used as leader of events.
>
> There are three options to fix the issue.
>
> 1. Do not expose /sys/bus/event_source/devices/cpu/events/slots to userspace so that pmu_have_event(pmu->name, "slots") returns false.
> 2. Run cpuid at perf userspace and avoid using 'slots' if it is not supported in cpuid.
> 3. Do not fatal perf if the leader is failed. Do not create events for an evsel if its leader is already failed.

So I tried to manually specify the events, not specifying `slots`:

```
./perf stat -e cache-misses -d ls

 Performance counter stats for 'ls':

             20145      cache-misses
            555870      L1-dcache-loads
             25832      L1-dcache-load-misses     #    4.65% of all L1-dcache accesses
   <not supported>      LLC-loads
   <not supported>      LLC-load-misses

       0.000948558 seconds time elapsed

       0.001025000 seconds user
       0.000000000 seconds sys
```

So, `perf` is finally useable in my WSL. Hope this helps people with similar errors.

Answer (score 0):

In my case (WSL2 Debian), I fixed this by installing `linux-perf`. It was after trying a couple answers here and reading [this WSL Issue](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/10829).