# How to use Linux perf tool on WSL2? How to have perf for the correct kernel?

Tags: linux, windows, linux-kernel, windows-subsystem-for-linux, perf

I am trying to use the perf tool of Linux on my WSL2 using Windows10 machine. I have done every step of the accepted answer here:[Is there any method to run perf under WSL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60237123/is-there-any-method-to-run-perf-under-wsl)

When I ran "make" comment, I got a warning:

> Warning: Kernel ABI header at 'tools/include/uapi/linux/stat.h'
> differs from latest version at 'include/uapi/linux/stat.h'

But the perf executable was still created.
However when I try to use perf like this:

```
sudo perf record -g myexe myargs
```

I received this error:

> WARNING: perf not found for kernel 5.10.16.3-microsoft
>
> You may need to install the following packages for this specific
> kernel:
> linux-tools-5.10.16.3-microsoft-standard-WSL2
> linux-cloud-tools-5.10.16.3-microsoft-standard-WSL2

Then I tried to run this:

```
sudo apt install linux-tools-5.10.16.3-microsoft-standard-WSL2
```

However that did not work either, I got this:

> Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree Reading state
> information... Done E: Unable to locate package
> linux-tools-5.10.16.3-microsoft-standard-WSL2 E: Couldn't find any
> package by glob 'linux-tools-5.10.16.3-microsoft-standard-WSL2'

What should I do now?

Comment: Are you sure you have WSL2?  Apparently it can be non-obvious whether a WSL install is actually WSL2 or WSL1: [Does WSL 2 really support 32 bit program?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61300194)

Comment: @PeterCordes hello! yes i am pretty sure, because it says version is 2 when I run the command "wsl --list --verbose".

Comment: On Debian 11 ("Bullseye") under WSL2, the `perf_5.10` command installed by the "linux-perf-5.10" package as a dependency of the "linux-perf" package seems to work.

Comment: perf looks at CPU hardware counters which will all return 0 in a VM.

Comment: @stark but i specifically researched to learn that perf works on WSL2

Comment: Have you succeeded with perf under WSL2?

Comment: Seems the only way is to build perf yourself. Not so hard per the instructions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60237123/is-there-any-method-to-run-perf-under-wsl

Answer (score 0):

Just run your newly built perf instead of the /usr/bin/perf which is a shell script to invoke real kernel-specific perf.

I usually replace the /usr/bin/perf with my own perf.

```
$ sudo ln -sf $(pwd)/perf /usr/bin/perf
```